# Can I install Ubuntu 16.04 parallel with Windows 8.1 on a Samsung RV513?

Tags: dual-boot

I have a Samsung RV513 laptop with an AMD E4540 1.65 GHz processor, 4 GB of RAM and a 320 GB HDD. Is my laptop compatible to run Ubuntu 16.04 in parallel with Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure! Go to  http://www.ubuntu.com/ and download whatever version you want, and burn it to a DVD-r or flash drive. When you boot from your live disc it will give you the option to side-install Ubuntu with Windows. It is very easy and doesn't require you to do any partitioning yourself. Enjoy Ubuntu!